# How to remove special characters from string using batch

Tags: string, batch-file, character

I have very little knowledge in batch programming.  I want to remove special characters from string    Suppose If  String= " How:to,convert special characters"   wants to convert into this " How-to-convert-special-characters   "                                                 ( how to do if there are multiple characters like ,; : )                Kindly help!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the substring replacement to change individual characters, as Peter Wright suggested, but this method preserve multiple characters, so a further change of multiple dashes by just one would be needed. If your objective is to separate *words* with just one dash eliminating multiple separation characters (even multiple spaces), then you may use a different method.

The `FOR` Batch command process *words* separated by spaces (single or multiple):

```
for %%a in (one two    three      four   ) do echo %%a
one
two
three
four
```

You may use *Delayed Expansion* to collect the words processed by `FOR` command into a single variable (for details, type `set /?` and look for "delayed expansion"):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set string=
for %%a in (   one   two   three   four  ) do set string=!string! %%a
echo "%string%"
" one two three four"
```

The standard separators for `FOR` *words* may be commas, semicolons and equal-signs, besides spaces (single or multiple):

```
for %%a in (one,two= ;; ,, three  ===;;;,,,   four ) do ...
```

This way, you may directly use a `FOR` command to eliminate multiple spaces, commas, semicolons (and equal-signs):

```
for %%a in (%string%) do ...
```

If you want to also eliminate one character more (like colon), you may change that character by space (or comma, semicolon or equal-sign) in the same `FOR` command:

```
for %%a in (%string::=;%) do
```

If you want to eliminate more characters, you may first change all of them in the string and then use `FOR`.

The Batch file below read a string and change multiple spaces, commas, semicolons, (equal-signs); colons and points, and insert a single dash between words:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /P input=Enter a string: 
set input=%input:.=,%
set output=
for %%a in (%input::=;%) do set output=!output!%%a-
rem Eliminate the last dash:
set output=%output:~0,-1%
echo Output: "%output%"
```

You must note that not all special characters can be processed this way.

Comment: Thank you this is working as I wanted.  I will take time for me to understand but right now I can use this code straight.  I am glad thanks again!

Comment: But what about characters like (){}[]*^/\ ? Is it possible to remove them in same way?

Answer (score 6):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET String=" How:to,convert special characters how to do if there are multiple characters like ,; : "
SET string1=%string:,=comma%
SET string2=%string:;=semicolon%
SET string3=%string::=fullcolon%
SET string4=%string3:;=SEMICOLON%
SET string4=%string4:,=COMMA%
SET string
```

The simple formula is SET varname2=%varname1:stringtoreplace=replacement%

It does have limits though. You would run into problems with certain characters like ^="% amongst others.

Comment: Its now working for me. Do I have to add anything to this code   Thanks